# Get image path from cache for https

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, ssl

I have a menu which has some images and I also use SSL certificate for the site. I saw that the images from menu are loaded through http on a https page and I'm getting that notice that the page isn't secure. Is there any way I can get it work without verifying the link and put manually there https?
This is what I have right now:

```
<img src="'.Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(165, 140).'" alt="'.$product->getName().'" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the protocol (https/http) to the cache key in order to distinguish http and https version of the block.

Comment: I am not sure where should I add this. Can you explain to me?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-block-caching/

Comment: Hmm..it seems to me that is too complicated to do something like this. I found something else but unfortunately doesn't work [http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/https-magento-cache-internet-explorer-no-image]